# Limit of $(\frac{1}{n^2})^{(\frac{1}{n})}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> **Question**: is this a valid procedure for finding the limit of $$\bigg(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)^{(\frac{1}{n})}$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

*background*: This is one of the examples of the failure of the root test to determine whether a sequence converges or diverges for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ in baby Rudin. I was wondering how one would compute the superior limit but thought that this might give a way to calculate the limit in general. I did manage to evaluate the limit to the correct answer but, am unsure if all of the techniques I used are valid. Thanks in advance.

*Proof*.
Set $x=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} x$. We may then rewrite the above as $$\bigg(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)^{(\frac{1}{n})}=(x^2)^x$$

Now let $y=(x^2)^x$. We will be attempting to use that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} y= \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}x^{2x}. $ It follows $\log y=\log ((x^2)^x)=\log(x^{2x})=2x\log x$. We may rewrite our limit again as, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{\log y}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} y = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{2x\log x}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} 2x\log x}$. Evaluating our previous limit, $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} 2x \log x=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}2\frac{\log x}{\frac{1}{x}}$$ by L'Hopitals rule we have
$$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}2\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}-2x=0$$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} y= e^0=1 $ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\big(\frac{1}{n^2}\big)^{(\frac{1}{n})}=1$.

Comment: Take the log. It will be faster.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ahh thank you. I was hoping you would have a faster proof ;)

Comment: Root Test is for series. There is no failure.